# Create Pandas Dataframe in Function

Tags: python, pandas, function, dataframe, data-structures

For a script I need to create dicts, lists and data frames at the beginning of the script. For that I do:

```
df4 = pd.DataFrame()
object_dict = {}
caption = []
```

Because there are a lot of different data frames, I would like to put that into a function like:

```
def create_data_objects():
  df4 = pd.DataFrame()
  object_dict = {}
  caption = []
```

But if I do so, I get "NameError: name 'df4' is not defined", so the data frame was not created. Is there a way to put this into a function and make my code more lean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create objects inside a function, their scope ends when the function ends.

You might consider doing this instead:

```
def create_data_objects():
  df4 = pd.DataFrame()
  object_dict = {}
  caption = []
  return df4, object_dict, caption

def MAIN_FUNCTION():
  df4, object_dict, caption = create_data_objects()
```